# Recursive method return and print Int number of String

Tags: java, recursion, methods, command-line, return

I'm having trouble with my recursive method. Which will return and print in my main method the X number of W. X being a positive integer on the commandline (arg[0]) and W is a String on the commandline (arg[1]).
So for what ever number it will print the string that much times.

For example my 1st commandline argument is "4" and my 2nd commandline argument is Hello.

Output should be printed as a string:

> "HelloHelloHelloHello"

I'm getting problems with my parameters being a int and a string I believe :( ?

My code atm:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      int number = new Integer(0);
      String word = new String("");
      number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      word = args[1];

      String method = recursive1.method1(word);
      System.out.println(method);
   }

   public static String method1(String word, int number) {
      if (number < 0){
         return 0;
      }
      else{
         return word + method1(number-1);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Errors? Please explain.

Comment: You cannot do `return 0` (integer) when you declare the method to return `String` + `method1` takes 2 arguments, you call in the else branch with only 1

Comment: and you cant call method1 with only one argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problem with your code. I've added commented wherever necessary;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ... // skipped previous lines
    // No need to use class name as main is static and method1 is also static.
    String method = method1(word, number); // Call the method with 2 parameters
    System.out.println(method);
}

// With an else - improves readability
public static String method1(String word, int number) {
    if (number == 0) { // If it is zero, return a blank string
        return ""; // return a blank string and not 0(int)
    } else {
        return word + method1(word, number - 1); // method1 requires 2 parameters
    }
}

// Without an else - unnecessary else removed
public static String method1(String word, int number) {
    if (number == 0) { // If it is zero, return a blank string
        return ""; // return a blank string and not 0(int)
    }
    // Removed the else as its really not necessary
    return word + method1(word, number - 1); // method1 requires 2 parameters
}
```

On a side note, you've 2 really unnecessary lines of code in the `main()` method.

```
  // int number = new Integer(0); // not needed
  // String word = new String(""); // not needed
  int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Since you're over-writing the value anyways
  String word = args[1]; // Since you're over-writing the value anyways
```

Comment: Dang, my biggest issue was not having those 2 parameters :o ! Also, thanks for the comments and code sample! Really helped in understanding how it works :)

Comment: and pls remove the else clause, its not necessary :)

Comment: Actually, with this kind of code, an `else` is an improvement in readability.  It makes it clearer to see that the second case only runs when the `if` isn't true.  In my opinion, this answer was better before the `else` was removed.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
public static String method1(String word, int number) {
    if (number < 1){
       return ""; // seems that if number is 0 or less, nothing will be printed
    }
    return word + method1(word, number-1);  
}
```

To print it:

```
System.out.println(method1(word, number));
```

Comment: @Asia x3: method1 take 2 params...this answer will solver your problem

Comment: hmmm and to print do I call it as : recursive1.method1(word,number) ?

Comment: aaah I kind of see now, my base case was pretty off huh

Comment: String method = recursive1.method1(word, number);
      System.out.println(method);

Comment: @ThanhLe and yeah, I needed two params the recursive method hmm

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
int number = new Integer(0);
```

This should better be:

```
int number = 0;
```

Or why not

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
```

right away? What purpose serves the initial 0?

And then, of course, when you define a method with n arguments, always call it with n arguments.

```
String result = method1(word, number);
```

Comment: Oh that's right, I could have just declared the new variable and parse  it, removing the unnecessary line of code :o

Answer (score 0):

try this code. There were some changes need to be done.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int number = new Integer(5); // you can comment this line when providing input from command line
  String word = new String("hello");// you can comment this line when providing input from command line
  number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  word = args[1];

  String method = method1(word,number);
  System.out.println(method);
}

public static String method1(String word, int number) {
  if (number == 0){
     return "";
  }
  else{
     return word + method1(word,number-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: @DavidWallace can you elaborate what is wrong in this ?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes that was just a small check i was just trying to give him hint. Anyways thanks for noticing it too :) Can you please give it to +1 now as i need to increase my rating in order to comment on some posts. Thanks.